# gradle, plugin and sdk version compatibility

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I am getting confused about the version numbers used for an android app. The source code is designed for

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ir.iiscenter.shub"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 25
    versionName "2.6.7"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

So, I want to know What is the correct version for `com.android.tools.build:gradle` and `com.google.gms:google-services` and `com.stanfy.spoon:spoon-gradle-plugin`.

Are those three numbers are the same as Project Structure->Project Gradle version, Android Plugin Version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know What is the correct version for com.android.tools.build:gradle and com.google.gms:google-services and com.stanfy.spoon:spoon-gradle-plugin.

There isn't a correct version.
There is a latest version and you can specify for each of them the version that you want to use.

**Just edit** the `root/build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    classpath 'com.stanfy.spoon:spoon-gradle-plugin:1.2.2'
  }
}
```

You can check the official doc:

- [Android plugin for gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)
- [Google play service plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin)
- [spoon-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/stanfy/spoon-gradle-plugin)